# Joomla: How can I output an article as JsonP?

Tags: php, json, joomla

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to output an article as JsonP? I need to consume it in a [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) application as a web service

```
Callback({'response': [{'<div>some random html content</div>'}], 'success': true});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.joomla.org/Ajax_using_MooTools#Generating_JSON_output

```
<?php
// Set up the data to be sent in the response.
$data = array( 'some data' );

// Get the document object.
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();

// Set the MIME type for JSON output.
$document->setMimeEncoding( 'application/json' );

// Change the suggested filename.
JResponse::setHeader( 'Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$view->getName().'.json"' );

// Output the JSON data.
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that documentation. But is that a Module or a Plugin? Where do you put it? I'm a .NET guy, so I'm a little unclear as to how I would approach this.

Comment: Just a thought, you might want to try searching http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: Plus, as far as I can tell, this isn't creating JSONP.

Comment: @YGomez - I went there and did the following search with NO results `+joomla +json`

Comment: i never tested it with json but i suppose its the same as xml , you create a view and give it an extension .json and when you call the article you add in the url &format=json

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to create a View. I've searched the help and the admin page. I'm using `Joomla! 1.5.18 Stable 27-May-2010 18:00 GMT ` and I've event tried appending `&format=xml` to a page, and I'm taken to a 500 error.

Comment: Also, if it helps. I currently **don't** have access to the file system... only *Super Administrator* within the CMS (though I "can" get file system access if needed)

Comment: from what i know , you need to have access to the file system since you will be creating new file (view.json.php)

Comment: I suggest you to read more aboutviews in joomla before proceeding

Comment: Yeah, I've been diggin around in the help, but doing a search for "view" in my local help doesn't turn anything up. I'm sure this isn't rocket science. I'll get it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

JSON Encode it with PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I know there's JSON Encode. I need a module to do this automagically.